# Disable screen turn-off during phone call

Tags: calls, screen, proximity-sensor

I know this might be a possible duplicate question but I haven't found an answer yet.

phone>call settings>proximity sensor is not available in my version of android.

Is there another way to disable the screen turning off when i dial or receive a phone call?

Is there an app i can install that does it?

Regarding the duplicate question: This question is different because i'm targeting android 4.x and beyond and because I want to disable the proximity sensor completely, it's broken on this device but even if it did work, I would like to override it somehow, preferably without having to install an app with ads etc.

Comment: May I ask why you want this? I've found that when my screen fails to turn itself off, which happens occasionally, the problem is quickly solved by my cheek hanging up the call for me. Regularly. Turning off the feature purposefully would prove disastrous.

Comment: Android screen blanks out during the call so you can't press 1 when they say: "press 1 for whatever".  Nothing brings the screen back up, volume buttons or power buttons.  Even holding the power down for 20 seconds does nothing.  All the thing does is occasionially flash the screen at you according to the proximity sensor, so waving your hand in front of the proximity sensor sometimes gets it working, but other times the entire phone is useless.  I can't press 1 to get to sales/service.  Forcing the screen on corrects for this Google/Android show-stopper bug.

Comment: if you change your screen, make sure the new one does not have any space on the part where the proximity sensor is, otherwise the mobile will get confused and think that the screen is actually your head answering a call

Answer (score 3):

Proximity sensors allow the screen to turn off when close to the ear during a call. It should automatically come back when it's uncovered i.e. when it's not close to the ear.

That said this app seems to promise that functionality -> [Smart Screen On Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.suriv.suscreen)

Comment: I have found this app to be ineffective on phone model Sony Xperia Z3.

Comment: I also found this to be ineffective on a Nexus 5X.